# Twilio call button and user input

Tags: javascript, twilio

so I've created this application that allows me to call a phone number from my Twilio account through localhost. I just have to put a / after the port # and the phone number I want to call(localhost:2222/7786453738) and it will send out a call. but I want the user to be able to make that call by inputting a phone number on to the webpage then clicking a button. is that possible? here's my code so far in the index.js file. I run it by going node index.js in the command terminal.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const port = 2222;

app.get("/", function(req, resp){
resp.end("welcome to my app");
});

app.get("/:data", function(req, resp){


var accountSid = 'accountSid'
var authToken = 'authtoken'

var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls.create({
url: 'https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/',
to: req.params.data,
from: '6043302056',
},  function(err, call) {
if(err) {
    console.log(err);
} else {
    console.log(call.sid);
}

})


console.log(req.params.data);
if(req.params.data == "me"){
    resp.end("hi raj");


    //resp.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/index.html)
} else {
    resp.end("Now calling: "+req.params.data);
}
});

app.listen(port, function(err){
if(err){
    console.log("error starting "+err);
    return false;
}

console.log("port is running. "+port);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're most of the way there with what you want to achieve. You can absolutely create a form that will take an input from a user and dial the number they enter.

First up, You will want to update your route as the number you send through a form won't be a part of the path, instead it will come as part of the body of the request. In order to read request bodies in express, you will want the `body-parser` module. So, install that in your project with:

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

Then include it in your file and use it with your app:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Now, form's usually POST their data, rather than working over GET, so let's update your route to receive that POST request and extract the number from the request:

```
app.post("/calls", function(req, resp) {
  const accountSid = 'accountSid'
  const authToken = 'authtoken'
  const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

  const number = req.body.number;

  client.calls.create({
    url: 'https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/',
    to: number,
    from: '6043302056',
  },  function(err, call) {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(call.sid);
    }
  })

  console.log(number);
  if(req.params.data == "me"){
    resp.end("hi raj");
    //resp.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/index.html)
  } else {
    resp.end("Now calling: " + number);
  }
});
```

Now, you need an HTML file that will include a form to make the request to this endpoint. Create an HTML file called `index.html` and place it in a new folder in your application called `public`.

You can load static files from the `public` directory in express with this line, add it near the top, after you create the `app`:

```
const path = require('path');
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Finally we just need the HTML. This is the simplest HTML I could write that would do what you need:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Make a call</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/" method="POST">
    <label for="number">What number do you want to call?</label>
    <input id="number" type="tel" />
    <button type="submit">Make call</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it is just a form with a single input, the number, and a button to submit it.

Give this all a go and let me know how you get on.

Comment: thanks evangelist. everything makes total sense, but I'm not too sure on how the loading of static files works. i have my html file in a public folder. but where do i insert (app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));) it just returns an error ("path not defined") and when i click make call it says "cannot POST"

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I made a mistake there. You should also require `path` from the standard library too. Add `const path = require("path");` to the top of your file and try again.

Comment: I've got the application working and the function works on local host, but I've now uploaded the site onto a heroku server and i get this error when i try to make a call. "Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found." any idea to why this would occur?

Answer (score -1):

Yes,

first: you can do that, but you need to write the code in HTML File or at least include this code in html file, and call the Twilo's function after you click on the respective button. For that first, render a HTML page, after user enters the address, on that HTML Page give input number and call now button feature. and after user clicks on the button, do:

```
function callNow() {
var num = document.getElementById('number').value;

  client.calls.create({
    url: 'https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/',
    to: num,
    from: '6043302056',
  },  function(err, call) {
  if(err) {
     console.log(err);
  } else {
     console.log(call.sid);
  }
{
```

Your HTML Code should be:

```
<input id="number">
<button onclick="callNow()">Call Now</button>
```

You can include twilio cdn and use this feature. I am just giving you the concept, I hope you will find this helpful.

Comment: I don't recommend doing this as you would need to store your credentials in the client, and they could be stolen and used against your account. Also, Twilio's API module doesn't work in the browser.

Comment: Then you should create a call on the server for the call, but in anyway you need to get user's number from user, then send real time message to server, then you can do that.

Comment: That is true, and I am writing that up as an answer :)